# Detecting elements boundaries on Alloy

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

My *onClick* event seems to not be firing, I have a button inside a `<ScrollView>`, and it does not give me any response, so I was wondering if there is a way to track which *object* was clicked so I could do the styling to make my *buttons* clickable again.

```
<Alloy>
<Window class="container">
    <View  class="insideContainer">
        <View layout="horizontal">
            <ImageView id="minLogo" image="/images/homeLogo.png" ></ImageView>

            <ScrollableView id="mainViewInterna">
                <View id="MainWelcomeText" class="MainWelcomeText rowLayout">
                    <Label class="welcomeText">BEM VINDO</Label>
                    <Label class="welcomeText">[ Usuário ]</Label>

                    <View class="button-row" width="200dp" height="200dp">
                        <Label id="logoutButton" class="button" onClick="logout">Log Out</Label>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ScrollableView>
        </View>     
    </View>
</Window>   
</Alloy>
```

The Function:

```
function logout(){
   Ti.API.log('it works');
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: don't be shy and share your code so we can help you!
Temos um canal br e pt no http://tislack.org, acessa aí que podemos te ajudar =)

Comment: added the code, so you people can help me further

Comment: Your controller contains only this function?

Comment: Try with Ti.API.info('it works');

Comment: Can you see the "Log Out" text?

Comment: Yes, I can see my logout text but the click is not firing yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var logout = function() {

    $.logoutButton.removeEventListener('click',logout);

    console.log('logout');
};

$.logoutButton.addEventListener('click',logout);
```

Comment: Why do you remove event listener?

Comment: Every time that I stop using a controller, I remove all events associated with it, lets say that you don't destroy that element, and just remove it, if you add it again and add another time the click event, it starts running that event more times, at least some few years ago this appended with me.

When I let the user click some times on the button, I just call the remove event on the container view destroy

Comment: Usually this is not needed, except only special cases.

Comment: strangely it worked, somehow, solved my issue with the logout button, iside of it I could call a global function that do the real logout from the app, but I still have the doubt if it is possible to see which event is firing.